# General Anchor css is overriding class...but only on one page

Tags: html, css

I have the following after my reset at around line 69

```
a, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #333;
  font-family: "museo";
  border-bottom: #444 solid 1px;
}
```

Then down at line 303 I have:

```
.leaderboard_ad {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 10px 36px;
  position: relative;
  width: 728px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom: #e4e4e4 solid 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ad_title {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.ad_subhead {
  color: green;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This is a development file, which is why I have the ad, it's a placeholder for adsense.

Now, on most pages it gives me the style I want. However on one page the leaderboard ad placeholder is being overwritten by the general anchor style, I cannot figure out why. The HTML was copied and pasted so it's 100% the same. It appears the correct way everywhere but one page...I've cleared my cache and it just keeps going. This seems to defy all logic. Any ideas?

The code for the HTML:

```
<div class="leaderboard_ad">
                <a href="#" class="ad_title">Ad Title</a>
                <a href="#" class="ad_subhead">www.google.com/adsense</a>
                <p>This is an example of a leaderboard AdSense text ad.</p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your selectors to `a.ad_title` and `a.ad_subhead` ?

Comment: I can try it. I'm not super worried about it because adsense will add it's own ads later on. I just thought it was the oddest error. The fact that all but one page offer the correct style and all of the css/html is written correctly...Boggles my mind.